# Sorting Visualizations - WinForms

Tags: c#, sorting, winforms

## Description

I think many many people have seen [this youtube video "15 Sorting Algorithms in 6 Minutes"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPRA0W1kECg)
When I saw it, I decided: "I can do that better" and I tried to get things done with the tools at my disposal back then. Windows Forms and C#. I added a functionality to allow the pausing of sorting in any point of time. Therefore I reasoned, my algoritms need to move step by step, and Implemented accordingly.

Since then much has changed and yesterday I revisited my code from then, and it was gruesome.

Not just bad, but horrible. So i went ahead and refactored what I could, removed superfluous stuff, decoupled implementations and algorithms, renamed methods to be more C#-ish, and realized, I have become a [java](/questions/tagged/java)-programmer by heart.

My method names got camelCased, there's no properties, and my Interface wasn't prefixed with I at the start.

Well, that aside, I finally arrived at something, where I am facing difficulties reducing the coupling. Where I am unsure what the best practice is, so here goes.

## Code

Windows Forms oh how I love it, here come the FormDesigner.cs and the Form.cs ;)

```csharp
namespace SortVisualizations
{
    partial class MainWindow
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Erforderliche Designervariable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Verwendete Ressourcen bereinigen.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">True, wenn verwaltete Ressourcen gelöscht werden sollen; andernfalls False.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Vom Windows Form-Designer generierter Code

        /// <summary>
        /// Erforderliche Methode für die Designerunterstützung.
        /// Der Inhalt der Methode darf nicht mit dem Code-Editor geändert werden.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.triggerExit = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.clock = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
            this.triggerFill = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.inputArrayLength = new System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown();
            this.triggerToggleSorting = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.dropDownSortAlgorithms = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
            this.labelInputArrayLength = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.labelDropDownAlgorithms = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.paintArea = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.inputArrayLength)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // triggerExit
            // 
            this.triggerExit.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
            this.triggerExit.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(981, 603);
            this.triggerExit.Name = "triggerExit";
            this.triggerExit.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(188, 82);
            this.triggerExit.TabIndex = 0;
            this.triggerExit.Text = "Beenden";
            this.triggerExit.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.triggerExit.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.triggerExit_Click);
            // 
            // clock
            // 
            this.clock.Interval = 10;
            this.clock.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.clock_Tick);
            // 
            // triggerFill
            // 
            this.triggerFill.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(981, 90);
            this.triggerFill.Name = "triggerFill";
            this.triggerFill.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(188, 74);
            this.triggerFill.TabIndex = 2;
            this.triggerFill.Text = "Array befuellen";
            this.triggerFill.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.triggerFill.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.triggerFill_Click);
            // 
            // inputArrayLength
            // 
            this.inputArrayLength.Increment = new decimal(new int[] {
            10,
            0,
            0,
            0});
            this.inputArrayLength.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(981, 47);
            this.inputArrayLength.Maximum = new decimal(new int[] {
            10000,
            0,
            0,
            0});
            this.inputArrayLength.Name = "inputArrayLength";
            this.inputArrayLength.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(187, 20);
            this.inputArrayLength.TabIndex = 3;
            this.inputArrayLength.TextAlign = System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            this.inputArrayLength.Value = new decimal(new int[] {
            10,
            0,
            0,
            0});
            this.inputArrayLength.ValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.ArrayLengthChange);
            // 
            // triggerToggleSorting
            // 
            this.triggerToggleSorting.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
            this.triggerToggleSorting.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(981, 499);
            this.triggerToggleSorting.Name = "triggerToggleSorting";
            this.triggerToggleSorting.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(188, 82);
            this.triggerToggleSorting.TabIndex = 5;
            this.triggerToggleSorting.Text = "Sortiere";
            this.triggerToggleSorting.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.triggerToggleSorting.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.triggerToggleSorting_Click);
            // 
            // dropDownSortAlgorithms
            // 
            this.dropDownSortAlgorithms.AllowDrop = true;
            this.dropDownSortAlgorithms.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.dropDownSortAlgorithms.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(980, 472);
            this.dropDownSortAlgorithms.Name = "dropDownSortAlgorithms";
            this.dropDownSortAlgorithms.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(189, 21);
            this.dropDownSortAlgorithms.TabIndex = 6;
            // 
            // labelInputArrayLength
            // 
            this.labelInputArrayLength.AutoSize = true;
            this.labelInputArrayLength.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(981, 12);
            this.labelInputArrayLength.Name = "labelInputArrayLength";
            this.labelInputArrayLength.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(185, 13);
            this.labelInputArrayLength.TabIndex = 4;
            this.labelInputArrayLength.Text = "Arraygröße des zu sortierenden Arrays";
            // 
            // labelDropDownAlgorithms
            // 
            this.labelDropDownAlgorithms.AutoSize = true;
            this.labelDropDownAlgorithms.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(981, 437);
            this.labelDropDownAlgorithms.Name = "labelDropDownAlgorithms";
            this.labelDropDownAlgorithms.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(170, 13);
            this.labelDropDownAlgorithms.TabIndex = 7;
            this.labelDropDownAlgorithms.Text = "Anzuwendender Sortieralgorithmus";
            // 
            // paintArea
            // 
            this.paintArea.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.paintArea.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 13);
            this.paintArea.Name = "paintArea";
            this.paintArea.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(946, 672);
            this.paintArea.TabIndex = 8;
            // 
            // MainWindow
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1181, 697);
            this.ControlBox = false;
            this.Controls.Add(this.paintArea);
            this.Controls.Add(this.labelDropDownAlgorithms);
            this.Controls.Add(this.dropDownSortAlgorithms);
            this.Controls.Add(this.triggerToggleSorting);
            this.Controls.Add(this.labelInputArrayLength);
            this.Controls.Add(this.inputArrayLength);
            this.Controls.Add(this.triggerFill);
            this.Controls.Add(this.triggerExit);
            this.MaximizeBox = false;
            this.MinimizeBox = false;
            this.Name = "MainWindow";
            this.ShowIcon = false;
            this.Text = "Sortieralgorithmen Visualisiert";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.inputArrayLength)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Button triggerExit;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer clock;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button triggerFill;
        private System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown inputArrayLength;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button triggerToggleSorting;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox dropDownSortAlgorithms;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label labelInputArrayLength;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label labelDropDownAlgorithms;
        public System.Windows.Forms.Panel paintArea;
    }
}
```

---

```csharp
namespace SortVisualizations
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Form
    {
        private const int STANDARD_ARRAY_SIZE = 10;
        private static ImplementationFactory algos = ImplementationFactory.Instance();

        private bool isSorting;
        private int[] arrayToSort;
        private IAlgoImplementation stepAlgorithm;

        private Stopwatch sw;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            init();
        }

        private void init()
        {
            this.arrayToSort = new int[STANDARD_ARRAY_SIZE];
            dropDownSortAlgorithms.SelectedValueChanged += selectAlgo;

            IEnumerator algoEnumerator = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Algorithm)).GetEnumerator();
            while (algoEnumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                dropDownSortAlgorithms.Items.Add(algoEnumerator.Current);
            }
            SelectAlgo(Algorithm.BUBBLESORT);

            clock.Start();
            sw = new Stopwatch();

            generateRandomArrayElements();
            isSorting = false;
        }

        private void getStepAlgorithm(Algorithm selected)
        {
            this.stepAlgorithm = algos.GetAlgoImplementationFor(selected, this, ref arrayToSort);
        }

        internal void SelectAlgo(Algorithm algo)
        {
            dropDownSortAlgorithms.SelectedItem = algo;
            getStepAlgorithm(algo);
        }

        public void SwapIndexes(int i, int p, ref int[] arrayToSort)
        {
            int temp;

            Control panelI = this.paintArea.Controls[i];
            Control panelP = this.paintArea.Controls[p];

            temp = arrayToSort[p];
            arrayToSort[p] = arrayToSort[i];
            arrayToSort[i] = temp;

            panelI.Height = (int)(paintArea.Height * arrayToSort[i] / arrayToSort.Length);
            panelP.Height = (int)(paintArea.Height * arrayToSort[p] / arrayToSort.Length);

            panelI.Top = paintArea.Height - panelI.Height;
            panelP.Top = paintArea.Height - panelP.Height;
        }


        public static void CreateAlert(string p)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(p);
        }

        private void ArrayLengthChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NumericUpDown uiArrayItemCountUpDown = sender as NumericUpDown;
            if ((int)uiArrayItemCountUpDown.Value <= 0){
                CreateAlert("Die Anzahl der Elemente kann nicht 0 oder weniger sein");
                uiArrayItemCountUpDown.Value = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                this.arrayToSort = new int[(int)uiArrayItemCountUpDown.Value];
                generateRandomArrayElements();
            }
        }

        private void generateRandomArrayElements()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayToSort.Length; i++)
            {
                arrayToSort[i] = rnd.Next(1, arrayToSort.Length + 1);
            }

            selectAlgo(dropDownSortAlgorithms, null);
            uiInitializePaintArea();
            sw.Stop();
            sw.Reset();
        }

        #region event handlers

        private void selectAlgo(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox uiComboBox = sender as ComboBox;
            getStepAlgorithm((Algorithm)uiComboBox.SelectedItem);
        }

        private void clock_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (isSorting)
            {
                stepAlgorithm.Step();
                if (stepAlgorithm.IsFinished())
                {
                    triggerToggleSorting_Click(null, null);
                    CreateAlert(String.Format("Alle Elemente sind sortiert\nDauer: {0}", sw.Elapsed));
                }
            }
        }

        private void triggerToggleSorting_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            isSorting = !isSorting;
            if (isSorting)
            {
                triggerToggleSorting.Text = "Pause";
                sw.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                triggerToggleSorting.Text = "Sortiere";
                sw.Stop();
            }
        }

        private void triggerExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void triggerFill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            generateRandomArrayElements();
        }
        #endregion

        #region ui modification methods
        private void uiInitializePaintArea()
        {
            if (arrayToSort.Length + 1 != paintArea.Controls.Count)
                uiCreateRepresentingPanels();

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayToSort.Length; i++)
            {
                //Should be able to match paintArea.Items[i] with arrayToSort[i]
                Control rectangle = paintArea.Controls.Find(String.Format("_{0}", i), true).First();

                //We do not need to adjust the width, as it always stays the same.
                rectangle.Height = (int)(paintArea.Height * arrayToSort[i] / arrayToSort.Length);
                rectangle.Top = (paintArea.Height - rectangle.Height);
            }

            paintArea.Update();
            paintArea.PerformLayout();
        }

        private void uiCreateRepresentingPanels()
        {
            paintArea.Controls.Clear();

            // the width stays the same for all rectangles
            int width = (int)(paintArea.Width / arrayToSort.Length);

            if (width == 0)
                width = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayToSort.Length; i++)
            {
                Panel rectangle = new Panel();
                rectangle.Name = String.Format("_{0}", i);
                rectangle.Width = width;
                rectangle.Height = (int)(paintArea.Height * arrayToSort[i] / arrayToSort.Length);
                rectangle.Left = width * i;
                rectangle.Top = (paintArea.Height - rectangle.Height);

                rectangle.BackColor = Color.Green;

                paintArea.Controls.Add(rectangle);
            }
        }

        internal void uiAssumeSorted(int index)
        {
            this.paintArea.Controls[index].BackColor = Color.Blue;
        }

        public void uiDeclarePivot(int index)
        {
            this.paintArea.Controls[index].BackColor = Color.Red;
        }

        public void uiRemovePivot(int index)
        {
            this.paintArea.Controls[index].BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

I tried to Hide my Algorithm implementations behind an interface, and use this Factory to instantiate them:

```csharp
class ImplementationFactory
{
    private static ImplementationFactory _instance;
    private Dictionary<Algorithm, IAlgoImplementation> mapping = new Dictionary<Algorithm, IAlgoImplementation>();

    private ImplementationFactory()
    {
        mapping.Add(Algorithm.BUBBLESORT, new BubbleSort());
        mapping.Add(Algorithm.COCKTAILSHAKER, new Cocktailshaker());
    }

    public static ImplementationFactory Instance()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
            _instance = new ImplementationFactory();

        return _instance;
    }

    public IAlgoImplementation GetAlgoImplementationFor(Algorithm algo, MainWindow owner, ref int[] array)
    {
        IAlgoImplementation impl;
        if (!mapping.TryGetValue(algo, out impl))
        {
            MainWindow.CreateAlert("Falling back to default algorithm!");
            owner.SelectAlgo(Algorithm.BUBBLESORT);
            if (!mapping.TryGetValue(Algorithm.BUBBLESORT, out impl))
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }
        }

        impl.Initialize(owner, ref array);
        return impl;
    }
}
```

And A few things on the Algorithms:

```csharp
public enum Algorithm
{
    BUBBLESORT, COCKTAILSHAKER
}
```

As well as the interface to unify them all:

```csharp
interface IAlgoImplementation
{
    void Initialize(MainWindow owner, ref int[] array);
    void Step();
    bool IsFinished();
}
```

Additionally for full runnability, here's the Bubblesort Algorithm Implementation. The Implementations may be part of another review, but I'd prefer to leave them out of this one.

```csharp
class BubbleSort : IAlgoImplementation
{
    private bool isFinished;
    private bool hasSwapped;

    private int current;
    private int assumeSortedFrom;

    private int[] array;

    private MainWindow owner;

    public BubbleSort()
    {

    }

    public void Initialize(MainWindow owner, ref int[] array)
    {
        this.isFinished = false;
        this.owner = owner;
        this.array = array;
        this.current = 0;
        this.assumeSortedFrom = array.Length;
    }

    public void Step()
    {
        owner.uiRemovePivot(current);
        if (current + 1 == assumeSortedFrom)
        {
            assumeSortedFrom = current;
            owner.uiAssumeSorted(current);
            current = 0;
            owner.uiDeclarePivot(current);
            if (!hasSwapped)
            {
                isFinished = true;
            }
            else
            {
                hasSwapped = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (array[current] > array[current + 1])
            {
                owner.SwapIndexes(current, current + 1, ref array);
                hasSwapped = true;
            }

            current++;
            owner.uiDeclarePivot(current);
        }
    }

    public bool IsFinished()
    {
        return isFinished;
    }
}
```

## Questions / Notes:

A few things I want to talk about, before you do:

1. Yes, that is hungarian notation there. I decided to prefix all UI-related methods, whereever reasonably possible with a `ui`. Please don't judge me on that.
2. Constants. I know this code could still use the extraction of a few constants. (String messages, mainly). These are duly noted and scheduled for purging.
3. Designer-Code and Comments. Well these are mostly german **and** auto-generated. I provided this mostly for the possibility of copying and then running it. If you want to rant, go on, but don't expect too many upvotes.

Especially concerned I am about:

1. Responsibilites of Classes: Did I pack too much into the MainWindow.cs?
2. Decoupling: I feel that this is all still waay to tightly coupled. How could I reduce that?
3. Ref-Passing the array: I got the gut-feeling I tinker with that thing too often and in the wrong places.
4. As always, everything else you want to mention ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Naming**

Methodnames in C# should be `PascalCase`
Some examples from your sources

> ```
> private void init()
> private void getStepAlgorithm(Algorithm selected)
> private void generateRandomArrayElements()
> private void uiInitializePaintArea()
> ```

As I read `clock` I thought, why is he showing a clock for a algorithm. I needed to check the declaration hidden inside the designer file to see it is a `timer`.
You should just name it timer.

> ```
> private void getStepAlgorithm(Algorithm selected)
> {
>     this.stepAlgorithm = algos.GetAlgoImplementationFor(selected, this, ref arrayToSort);
> }
> ```

Reading the methodname `getStepAlgorithm` let a reader assume that he is getting an algorithm but what the code does is assigning an algorithm to a class field. So a better name would be `AssignAlgorithm`

**Decoupling**

Communication between parent, here `MainWindow`, and child, here an inplementation of the `IAlgoImplementation` interface, should be by calling methods and setting of properties. From child to parent it should be done by events. The implementation of the `IAlgoImplementation` should know nothing of its parent. Also the factory should know nothing of the `MainWindow`.

> ```
>  public void SwapIndexes(int i, int p, ref int[] arrayToSort)
> ```

This method of the `MainWindow` class is violating separations of concerns, because it is called from the `BubbleSort` implementation of the `IAlgoImplementation` interface.

**Refactoring**
First we should change the name of `interface IAlgoImplementation` to `interface ISortAlgorithm` to make the name more meaningful. The same we do to the `void Step()` method and rename it to `void PerformSortStep()`. We add a property to hold the array to be sorted and add events for performing a sortstep, swapping values and for finishing the sorting.

```
interface ISortAlgorithm
{
    int[] ArrayToSort { set; }

    void PerformSortStep();

    event EventHandler<SortStepPerformedEventArgs> SortStepPerformed;
    event EventHandler<SwapPerformedEventArgs> SwapPerformed;
    event EventHandler SortFinished;
}
```

---

```
public class SortStepPerformedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int CurrentIndex { get; private set; }
    public PointOfStep StepPoint { get; private set; }
    public SortStepPerformedEventArgs(int currentIndex, PointOfStep stepPoint)
    {
        CurrentIndex = currentIndex;
        StepPoint = stepPoint;
    }
}
```

---

```
public enum PointOfStep
{
    BeforeStep, ReAssignedAssumeSorted, CurrentStep
}
```

---

```
public class SwapPerformedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int FirstIndex { get; private set; }
    public int SecondIndex { get; private set; }
    public int FirstValue { get; private set; }
    public int SecondValue { get; private set; }
    public int LengthOfArrayToSort { get; set; }

    public SwapPerformedEventArgs(int firstIndex, int secondIndex, 
        int firstValue, int secondValue, 
        int lengthOfArrayToSort)
    {
        FirstIndex = firstIndex;
        SecondIndex = secondIndex;
        FirstValue = firstValue;
        SecondValue = secondValue;
        LengthOfArrayToSort = lengthOfArrayToSort;
    }

}
```

---

Now let us take a look at the `BubbleSort` class. As you didn't implement the interface explicit, I added a `private get` to the `ArrayToSort` property.

```
public class BubbleSort : ISortAlgorithm
{
    private int current;
    private int assumeSortedFrom;
    private bool hasSwapped;

    private int[] arrayToSort = null;
    public int[] ArrayToSort
    {
        set {
            if (value == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("ArrayToSort", "The array to be sorted can't be null");
            }
            arrayToSort = value;
            InitializeSorting();

        }
        private get { return arrayToSort; }
    }

    private void InitializeSorting()
    {
        current = 0;
        assumeSortedFrom = ArrayToSort.Length;
        hasSwapped = false;

    }

    public void PerformSortStep()
    {

        OnSortStepPerformed(current, PointOfStep.BeforeStep);

        if (current + 1 == assumeSortedFrom)
        {
            assumeSortedFrom = current;
            OnSortStepPerformed(current, PointOfStep.ReAssignedAssumeSorted);

            current = 0;
            OnSortStepPerformed(current, PointOfStep.CurrentStep);

            if (!hasSwapped)
            {
                OnSortFinished();
            }
            else
            {
                hasSwapped = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (ArrayToSort[current] > ArrayToSort[current + 1])
            {
                SwapIndexes(current, current + 1);
                hasSwapped = true;
            }

            current++;
            OnSortStepPerformed(current, PointOfStep.CurrentStep);
        }
    }

    private void SwapIndexes(int currentIndex, int nextIndex)
    {
        int temp;

        temp = arrayToSort[nextIndex];
        ArrayToSort[nextIndex] = ArrayToSort[currentIndex];
        ArrayToSort[currentIndex] = temp;

        SwapPerformedEventArgs e = new SwapPerformedEventArgs(currentIndex, nextIndex,
            ArrayToSort[currentIndex], ArrayToSort[nextIndex], 
            ArrayToSort.Length);

        OnSwapPerformed(e);

    }

    object objectLock = new Object();
    private EventHandler<SortStepPerformedEventArgs> sortStepPerformed;
    public event EventHandler<SortStepPerformedEventArgs> SortStepPerformed
    {
        add
        {
            lock (objectLock)
            {
                sortStepPerformed += value;
            }
        }
        remove
        {
            lock (objectLock)
            {
                sortStepPerformed -= value;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnSortStepPerformed(int currentIndex, PointOfStep pointOfStep)
    {
        OnSortStepPerformed(new SortStepPerformedEventArgs(currentIndex, pointOfStep));
    }

    private void OnSortStepPerformed(SortStepPerformedEventArgs e)
    {
        lock (objectLock)
        {
            if (sortStepPerformed != null)
            {
                sortStepPerformed(this, e);
            }
        }
    }

    private EventHandler<SwapPerformedEventArgs> swapPerformed;
    public event EventHandler<SwapPerformedEventArgs> SwapPerformed
    {
        add
        {
            lock (objectLock)
            {
                swapPerformed += value;
            }
        }
        remove
        {
            lock (objectLock)
            {
                swapPerformed -= value;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnSwapPerformed(SwapPerformedEventArgs e)
    {
        lock (objectLock)
        {
            if (swapPerformed != null)
            {
                swapPerformed(this, e);
            }
        }
    }

    private event EventHandler sortFinished;
    public event EventHandler SortFinished
    {
        add
        {
            lock (objectLock)
            {
                sortFinished += value;
            }
        }
        remove
        {
            lock (objectLock)
            {
                sortFinished -= value;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnSortFinished()
    {
        lock (objectLock)
        {
            if (sortFinished != null)
            {
                sortFinished(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

No reference to any calling `owner` is needed anymore.

As the factory class also has been coupled with the `MainWindow` we need to decouple this also.

> ```
>     public IAlgoImplementation GetAlgoImplementationFor(Algorithm algo, MainWindow owner, ref int[] array)
>     {
>         IAlgoImplementation impl;
>         if (!mapping.TryGetValue(algo, out impl))
>         {
>             MainWindow.CreateAlert("Falling back to default algorithm!");
>             owner.SelectAlgo(Algorithm.BUBBLESORT);
>             if (!mapping.TryGetValue(Algorithm.BUBBLESORT, out impl))
>             {
>                 throw new NotSupportedException();
>             }
>         }
>         impl.Initialize(owner, ref array);
>         return impl;
>     }
> ```

First we rename the class to `SortAlgorithmFactory`. Now we add a property `IEnumerator ImplementedAlgorithms` to return the algorithms which the factory can create.

```
class SortAlgorithmFactory
{

    private static SortAlgorithmFactory _instance;
    private Dictionary<Algorithm, ISortAlgorithm> mapping = new Dictionary<Algorithm, ISortAlgorithm>();

    public IEnumerator ImplementedAlgorithms
    {
        get { return mapping.Keys.GetEnumerator(); }
    }

    private SortAlgorithmFactory()
    {
        mapping.Add(Algorithm.BUBBLESORT, new BubbleSort());
        mapping.Add(Algorithm.COCKTAILSHAKER, new Cocktailshaker());
    }

    public static SortAlgorithmFactory Instance()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
            _instance = new SortAlgorithmFactory();

        return _instance;
    }

    public ISortAlgorithm GetAlgoImplementationFor(Algorithm algo, int[] array)
    {
        ISortAlgorithm sortAlgorithm = mapping[algo];
        sortAlgorithm.ArrayToSort = array;

        return sortAlgorithm;
    }
}
```

Now there is no reference to the `MainWindow` anymore. Also by using the `ImplementedAlgorithms` property, we remove the possibility of an infinite loop for the case someone commented this `mapping.Add(Algorithm.BUBBLESORT, new BubbleSort());`.

Let us now move to the `MainWindow`.

> ```
> private void generateRandomArrayElements()
> {
>     Random rnd = new Random();
>
>     for (int i = 0; i < arrayToSort.Length; i++)
>     {
>         arrayToSort[i] = rnd.Next(1, arrayToSort.Length + 1);
>     }
>
>     selectAlgo(dropDownSortAlgorithms, null);
>     uiInitializePaintArea();
>     sw.Stop();
>     sw.Reset();
> }
> ```

This method does a lot of things, not only generating random array elements, but also selecting an algorithm ...  so, let us refactor the method and the 3 usages of this method

```
    private Random rnd = new Random();
    private void GenerateRandomArrayElements()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayToSort.Length; i++)
        {
            arrayToSort[i] = rnd.Next(1, arrayToSort.Length + 1);
        }

        sw.Stop();
        sw.Reset();

    }
```

---

```
    private void ArrayLengthChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NumericUpDown uiArrayItemCountUpDown = sender as NumericUpDown;
        if ((int)uiArrayItemCountUpDown.Value <= 0)
        {
            ShowAlert("Die Anzahl der Elemente kann nicht 0 oder weniger sein");
            uiArrayItemCountUpDown.Value = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            this.arrayToSort = new int[(int)uiArrayItemCountUpDown.Value];
            GenerateRandomArrayElements();
            AssignArrayToSortAlgorithm();
            uiInitializePaintArea();
        }
    }
```

---

```
    private void triggerFill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        isSorting = false;
        GenerateRandomArrayElements();
        AssignArrayToSortAlgorithm();
        uiInitializePaintArea();
    }
```

---

And last but not least the former `init()` method

```
    private void Initialize()
    {
        this.arrayToSort = new int[STANDARD_ARRAY_SIZE];

        IEnumerator algoEnumerator = algorithmFactory.ImplementedAlgorithms;
        while (algoEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            dropDownSortAlgorithms.Items.Add(algoEnumerator.Current);
        }

        dropDownSortAlgorithms.SelectedValueChanged += SelectAlgorithm;

        StepTimer.Start();
        sw = new Stopwatch();

        GenerateRandomArrayElements();

        SelectAlgorithm(Algorithm.BUBBLESORT);

        uiInitializePaintArea();

        isSorting = false;
    }
```

---

The complete `MainWindow` class (note I have also renamed `clock` to `StepTimer`)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Form
{
    private const int STANDARD_ARRAY_SIZE = 10;
    private static SortAlgorithmFactory algorithmFactory = SortAlgorithmFactory.Instance();
    private bool isSorting;
    private int[] arrayToSort;
    private ISortAlgorithm sortAlgorithm;

    private Stopwatch sw;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        this.arrayToSort = new int[STANDARD_ARRAY_SIZE];

        IEnumerator algoEnumerator = algorithmFactory.ImplementedAlgorithms;
        while (algoEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            dropDownSortAlgorithms.Items.Add(algoEnumerator.Current);
        }

        dropDownSortAlgorithms.SelectedValueChanged += SelectAlgorithm;

        StepTimer.Start();
        sw = new Stopwatch();

        GenerateRandomArrayElements();

        SelectAlgorithm(Algorithm.BUBBLESORT);

        uiInitializePaintArea();

        isSorting = false;
    }

    private void AssignStepAlgorithm(Algorithm selected)
    {
        RemoveSortAlgorithmEventHandler();

        this.sortAlgorithm = algorithmFactory.GetAlgoImplementationFor(selected, arrayToSort);

        AddSortAlgorithmEventHandler();
    }

    private void AssignArrayToSortAlgorithm()
    {
        sortAlgorithm.ArrayToSort = arrayToSort;
    }

    private void RemoveSortAlgorithmEventHandler()
    {
        if (this.sortAlgorithm == null) { return; }
        this.sortAlgorithm.SortFinished -= new EventHandler(StepAlgorithm_SortFinished);
        this.sortAlgorithm.SortStepPerformed -= new EventHandler<SortStepPerformedEventArgs>
            (StepAlgorithm_SortStepPerformed);
        this.sortAlgorithm.SwapPerformed -= new EventHandler<SwapPerformedEventArgs>(StepAlgorithm_SwapPerformed);
    }

    private void AddSortAlgorithmEventHandler()
    {
        this.sortAlgorithm.SortFinished += new EventHandler(StepAlgorithm_SortFinished);
        this.sortAlgorithm.SortStepPerformed += new EventHandler<SortStepPerformedEventArgs>
            (StepAlgorithm_SortStepPerformed);
        this.sortAlgorithm.SwapPerformed += new EventHandler<SwapPerformedEventArgs>(StepAlgorithm_SwapPerformed);
    }

    void StepAlgorithm_SwapPerformed(object sender, SwapPerformedEventArgs e)
    {

        int arrayLength = e.LengthOfArrayToSort;

        Control panelI = this.paintArea.Controls[e.FirstIndex];
        Control panelP = this.paintArea.Controls[e.SecondIndex];

        panelI.Height = (int)(paintArea.Height * e.FirstValue / arrayLength);
        panelP.Height = (int)(paintArea.Height * e.SecondValue / arrayLength);

        panelI.Top = paintArea.Height - panelI.Height;
        panelP.Top = paintArea.Height - panelP.Height;

    }

    void StepAlgorithm_SortStepPerformed(object sender, SortStepPerformedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.StepPoint)
        {
            case PointOfStep.BeforeStep:
                uiRemovePivot(e.CurrentIndex);
                break;

            case PointOfStep.ReAssignedAssumeSorted:
                uiAssumeSorted(e.CurrentIndex);
                break;

            case PointOfStep.CurrentStep:
                uiDeclarePivot(e.CurrentIndex);
                break;
        }

    }

    void StepAlgorithm_SortFinished(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        triggerToggleSorting_Click(null, null);
        ShowAlert(String.Format("Alle Elemente sind sortiert\nDauer: {0}", sw.Elapsed));
    }

    private void SelectAlgorithm(Algorithm algorithm)
    {
        dropDownSortAlgorithms.SelectedItem = algorithm;
    }

    private void ShowAlert(string p)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(p);
    }

    private void ArrayLengthChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NumericUpDown uiArrayItemCountUpDown = sender as NumericUpDown;
        if ((int)uiArrayItemCountUpDown.Value <= 0)
        {
            ShowAlert("Die Anzahl der Elemente kann nicht 0 oder weniger sein");
            uiArrayItemCountUpDown.Value = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            this.arrayToSort = new int[(int)uiArrayItemCountUpDown.Value];
            GenerateRandomArrayElements();
            AssignArrayToSortAlgorithm();
            uiInitializePaintArea();
        }
    }

    private Random rnd = new Random();
    private void GenerateRandomArrayElements()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayToSort.Length; i++)
        {
            arrayToSort[i] = rnd.Next(1, arrayToSort.Length + 1);
        }

        sw.Stop();
        sw.Reset();

    }

    #region event handlers

    private void SelectAlgorithm(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox uiComboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        AssignStepAlgorithm((Algorithm)uiComboBox.SelectedItem);
    }

    private void StepTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (isSorting)
        {
            sortAlgorithm.PerformSortStep();
        }
    }

    private void triggerToggleSorting_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        isSorting = !isSorting;
        if (isSorting)
        {
            triggerToggleSorting.Text = "Pause";
            sw.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            triggerToggleSorting.Text = "Sortiere";
            sw.Stop();
        }
    }

    private void triggerExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void triggerFill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        isSorting = false;
        GenerateRandomArrayElements();
        AssignArrayToSortAlgorithm();
        uiInitializePaintArea();
    }
    #endregion

    #region ui modification methods
    private void uiInitializePaintArea()
    {
        if (arrayToSort.Length + 1 != paintArea.Controls.Count)
        {
            uiCreateRepresentingPanels();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayToSort.Length; i++)
        {
            //Should be able to match paintArea.Items[i] with arrayToSort[i]
            Control rectangle = paintArea.Controls.Find(String.Format("_{0}", i), true).First();

            //We do not need to adjust the width, as it always stays the same.
            rectangle.Height = (int)(paintArea.Height * arrayToSort[i] / arrayToSort.Length);
            rectangle.Top = (paintArea.Height - rectangle.Height);
        }

        paintArea.Update();
        paintArea.PerformLayout();
    }

    private void uiCreateRepresentingPanels()
    {
        paintArea.Controls.Clear();

        // the width stays the same for all rectangles
        int width = (int)(paintArea.Width / arrayToSort.Length);

        if (width == 0)
            width = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayToSort.Length; i++)
        {
            Panel rectangle = new Panel();
            rectangle.Name = String.Format("_{0}", i);
            rectangle.Width = width;
            rectangle.Height = (int)(paintArea.Height * arrayToSort[i] / arrayToSort.Length);
            rectangle.Left = width * i;
            rectangle.Top = (paintArea.Height - rectangle.Height);

            rectangle.BackColor = Color.Green;

            paintArea.Controls.Add(rectangle);
        }
    }

    private void uiAssumeSorted(int index)
    {
        this.paintArea.Controls[index].BackColor = Color.Blue;
    }

    private void uiDeclarePivot(int index)
    {
        this.paintArea.Controls[index].BackColor = Color.Red;
    }

    private void uiRemovePivot(int index)
    {
        this.paintArea.Controls[index].BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Using an abstract class can lead towards less code, if one want to implement the ISortAlgorithm explicit.

```
public abstract class SortAlgorithm : ISortAlgorithm
{
    protected int current;
    protected int assumeSortedFrom;
    protected bool hasSwapped;
    private int[] arrayToSort = null;
    protected int[] ArrayToSort { get { return arrayToSort; } }
    int[] ISortAlgorithm.ArrayToSort
    {
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("ArrayToSort", "The array to be sorted can't be null");
            }
            arrayToSort = value;
            InitializeSorting();

        }
    }
    private void InitializeSorting()
    {
        current = 0;
        assumeSortedFrom = ArrayToSort.Length;
        hasSwapped = false;

    }

    void ISortAlgorithm.PerformSortStep()
    {
        this.PerformSortStep();
    }

    protected abstract void PerformSortStep();
    protected abstract void SwapIndexes(int currentIndex, int nextIndex);

    object objectLock = new Object();
    private EventHandler<SortStepPerformedEventArgs> sortStepPerformed;
    event EventHandler<SortStepPerformedEventArgs> ISortAlgorithm.SortStepPerformed
    {
        add
        {
            lock (objectLock)
            {
                sortStepPerformed += value;
            }
        }
        remove
        {
            lock (objectLock)
            {
                sortStepPerformed -= value;
            }
        }
    }
    protected void OnSortStepPerformed(int currentIndex, PointOfStep pointOfStep)
    {
        OnSortStepPerformed(new SortStepPerformedEventArgs(currentIndex, pointOfStep));
    }
    protected void OnSortStepPerformed(SortStepPerformedEventArgs e)
    {
        lock (objectLock)
        {
            if (sortStepPerformed != null)
            {
                sortStepPerformed(this, e);
            }
        }
    }
    private EventHandler<SwapPerformedEventArgs> swapPerformed;
    event EventHandler<SwapPerformedEventArgs> ISortAlgorithm.SwapPerformed
    {
        add
        {
            lock (objectLock)
            {
                swapPerformed += value;
            }
        }
        remove
        {
            lock (objectLock)
            {
                swapPerformed -= value;
            }
        }
    }
    protected void OnSwapPerformed(SwapPerformedEventArgs e)
    {
        lock (objectLock)
        {
            if (swapPerformed != null)
            {
                swapPerformed(this, e);
            }
        }
    }
    private event EventHandler sortFinished;
    event EventHandler ISortAlgorithm.SortFinished
    {
        add
        {
            lock (objectLock)
            {
                sortFinished += value;
            }
        }
        remove
        {
            lock (objectLock)
            {
                sortFinished -= value;
            }
        }
    }
    protected void OnSortFinished()
    {
        lock (objectLock)
        {
            if (sortFinished != null)
            {
                sortFinished(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class BubbleSort:SortAlgorithm
{
    protected override void PerformSortStep()
    {
        OnSortStepPerformed(current, PointOfStep.BeforeStep);

        if (current + 1 == assumeSortedFrom)
        {
            assumeSortedFrom = current;
            OnSortStepPerformed(current, PointOfStep.ReAssignedAssumeSorted);

            current = 0;
            OnSortStepPerformed(current, PointOfStep.CurrentStep);

            if (!hasSwapped)
            {
                OnSortFinished();
            }
            else
            {
                hasSwapped = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (ArrayToSort[current] > ArrayToSort[current + 1])
            {
                SwapIndexes(current, current + 1);
                hasSwapped = true;
            }

            current++;
            OnSortStepPerformed(current, PointOfStep.CurrentStep);
        }
    }
    protected override void SwapIndexes(int currentIndex, int nextIndex)
    {
        int temp;

        temp = ArrayToSort[nextIndex];
        ArrayToSort[nextIndex] = ArrayToSort[currentIndex];
        ArrayToSort[currentIndex] = temp;

        SwapPerformedEventArgs e = new SwapPerformedEventArgs(currentIndex, nextIndex,
            ArrayToSort[currentIndex], ArrayToSort[nextIndex],
            ArrayToSort.Length);

        OnSwapPerformed(e);

    }
}
```